# SwiftUI navigating to detail after creation

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigation, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm trying to understand how to navigate in a "non-linear" way in SwiftUI with NavigationLink. So my use case is the following:

I have a list of items (which is already a detail view reached via NavigationLink), with a button to add a new item. When I click this button I open the "flow" needed to create the new item for the list, this flow is composed of multiple pages. In the last page I need to make my api call to create the item in my remote DB and when successful, I need to navigate to the detail of this newly created item, but if I press back it needs to go back to the list and not the creation steps.

***-- EDIT:*** So, I managed to make it work, but the effect is ugly, animating back to the list and animating again to the detail. Is there a way to go directly to the detail and removing silently the unwanted vies from the stack?

I made it work like this

```
class JoinTablePresentation: ObservableObject {
    @Published var shown: Bool = false
    @Published var showDetail: Bool = false
    @Published var tableId: String = ""

    func finishCreation(tableId: String){
        self.tableId = tableId
        shown = false
        showDetail = true
    }
}
```

This is the creation page

```
public struct JoinTable: View {
    @Inject var viewModel: JoinTableViewModel
    var restaurantId: String
    @EnvironmentObject var presentation: JoinTablePresentation

    public var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CodeScannerView(codeTypes: [.qr], simulatedData: "2S4SF5D3", completion: { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let qr):
                    viewModel.joinTable(code: qr, restaurantId: restaurantId)
                case .failure(let error): print(error)
                }
            })
        }.onReceive(viewModel.$joined) { state in
                switch state {
                case .idle: break
                case .loading: break
                case .failure(let error): print(error)
                case .done(let tableId): presentation.finishCreation(tableId: tableId)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

And this is the list view that shows the "add" and the further detail

```
public struct RestaurantDetail: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var navigation: Navigation
    let restaurantId: String
    let viewModel: RestaurantDetailViewModel
    @ObservedObject var presentation: JoinTablePresentation = JoinTablePresentation()

    init(restaurantId: String, restaurantDetailViewModel: RestaurantDetailViewModel = resolve()) {
        self.restaurantId = restaurantId
        viewModel = restaurantDetailViewModel
    }

    public var body: some View {
        let tables = viewModel.tables
        ScrollView {
            ZStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: JoinTable(restaurantId: restaurantId).environmentObject(presentation), isActive: $presentation.shown) {
                    EmptyView()
                }.isDetailLink(false)
                NavigationLink(destination: TableDetail(tableId: presentation.tableId).environmentObject(presentation), isActive: $presentation.showDetail){
                    EmptyView()
                }.isDetailLink(false)
                LazyVStack(content: {
                    ForEach(tables, id: \.id) { table in
                        TableItem(table: table)
                            .contextMenu {
                                Button(action: {}, label: { Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash") })
                            }
                    }
                })
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle("Ordini")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: HStack {
                Button(action: { $presentation.shown.wrappedValue = true }) {
                    Image(systemName: "qrcode.viewfinder")
                        .renderingMode(.original)
                }.accentColor(Color.OnSurface)
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Image("Add")
                }
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not present a sheet from the bottom of the screen? It will feel much more natural than navigating to another screen and then back again.

Comment: I see what you mean but I need to do it with a screen